# Security.stripInaccessible not returning Id of new records (running as sys admin)

Tags: apex, dml

I am trying to update my existing code to use the fancy new **Security.stripInaccessible** method. My current code to create records is very generic and so I have a method header something like the following -

```
insertRecords(List<SObject> stuff);
```

The only problem is that this method does not look to pass back the Id of the records, which can be critical if I am then trying to move forward and create children for those records. Here is example code and the resulting debug response.

I am running everything right now as sys admin so feel I should not have an issue with security.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    /*
        HelperDatabase.NoIdReturnedTest();
     */
    public static void NoIdReturnedTest()
    {
        //create account
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'My No Id Account';
        
        List<SObject> accts = new List<SObject>{acc};
        SObjectAccessDecision dec = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.CREATABLE, accts);

        Database.insert(dec.getRecords());

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'Look.....no Id returned - ' + acc.Id);

    }
```

Response logs -

```
Execute Anonymous: HelperDatabase.NoIdReturnedTest();
09:29:59.408 (408576179)|EXECUTION_STARTED
09:29:59.408 (408613149)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
09:29:59.408 (409237608)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
09:29:59.408 (413521752)|DML_BEGIN|[102]|Op:Insert|Type:SObject|Rows:1
09:29:59.408 (521681868)|DML_END|[102]
09:29:59.408 (521975999)|USER_DEBUG|[104]|DEBUG|Look.....no Id returned - null
09:29:59.408 (522004779)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
09:29:59.570 (570240757)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
09:29:59.570 (570240757)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|simpli_lv|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

09:29:59.570 (570240757)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

09:29:59.408 (570341586)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
09:29:59.408 (570362042)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Security.stripInaccessible` returns a *copy* of the records, not the *original* records. This means that `acc` and `accts` wasn't inserted, but rather a *copy* of `acc` and `accts`. That's where the Id values went off to. This behavior has the benefit of allowing the developer to see what was in memory before and after the security decisions were applied.

You can prove it to yourself that it wasn't the original list with the following code:

```
//create account
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = 'My No Id Account';

List<SObject> accts = new List<SObject>{acc};
SObjectAccessDecision dec = System.Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.CREATABLE, accts);
Account[] accts2 = dec.getRecords();

// Memory compare--assertion failed!
System.assert(accts === accts2, 'Different objects in memory');
// Or, you can compare the original record to the new one
System.assert(acc === accts2[0], 'Different objects in memory');
```

If you want to get the values back, make sure you're using the new List, and new record, instead:

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = 'My No Id Account';

List<SObject> accts = new List<SObject>{acc};
SObjectAccessDecision dec = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.CREATABLE, accts);
// Assign the results from getRecords to accts
Database.insert(accts = dec.getRecords());
// Assign the copied object back to acc
acc = accts[0]; 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'Here is the new Id: ' + acc.Id);
```

Comment: Yup, exactly the issue. Hats off kind sir.